# Why is coroutine 'hello_world' not awaiting correctly?

Tags: python-asyncio

This is an adapted version of 'hello world' from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio.html#module-asyncio). It works as expected.

```
"""hello_world.py"""
import asyncio


async def hello_world():
    print('Hello', end=' ')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('world.')
    

async def coro_runner(func):
    await func()

asyncio.run(coro_runner(hello_world))
```

I want to leave the asyncio environment, work with regular functions (i.e. not coroutines) and then return to the asyncio environment. To this end I wrote a new 'hello world'.

The await statement isn't working as expected. It does not return control to the coroutine. The program terminates prematurely without sleeping for a year.

Why?

```
"""so_bad_hw.py"""
import asyncio
from typing import Callable


async def hello_world():
    print('Hello', end=' ')
    await asyncio.sleep(31_536_000)  # 1 Year
    print('world.')
    
    
async def func_runner(func: Callable):
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    func()  # Calls not_a_coroutine

    
async def coro_runner(func: Callable):
    await func()  # Calls hello_world

    
def not_a_coroutine():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.create_task(coro_runner(hello_world))


asyncio.run(func_runner(not_a_coroutine))
```

This is the output:

```
so_bad_hw.py 
Hello 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Why would you do this? If func_runer is a co-routine you have nothing to gain by not using co-routines for async functions.

Comment: You never await the task you create with `loop.create_task(coro_runner(hello_world))`. `asyncio.run` will keep the event loop running until `func_runner(not_a_coroutine)` is done, giving anything else scheduled one last chance to run. Since `hello_world` is still sleeping, the loop moves on and stops.

Comment: @Eric Yang. Callbacks from Python libraries such as Tkinter sometimes need to call blocking IO. If those callbacks are to asyncio's StreamReader or StreamWriter you need a mechanism to interwork the asyncio and non-asyncio environments. Tkinter can't wait for anything. It was never designed for delay of any kind and is unlikely to ever be changed.
so_bad_hw.py explores the idea of making the  non-asyncio environment subordinate to a primarily asyncio program.
An alternative architecture which makes the asyncio and non-asyncio environments equal partners needs a complicated  foundation.

Comment: @dirn. I've added the program output. The coroutine hello_world does start as we can see the printed 'Hello'. 
hello_world is awaited by coro_runner. There is no warning that hello_world was not awaited. 
It does not sleep for a year so it is certain that the program ended either before or after the await statement in hello_world.

Comment: @dirn 2. Try removing the await statement in coro_runner: You'll see Python raises the warning  'coroutine 'hello_world' was never awaited'.
Then try removing the complete await statement and sleep line in hello_world. You'll see that both 'Hello' and 'world.' get printed.
Also, it doesn't matter what coroutine follows the await statement - it just doesn't run.

Comment: This is all because you don’t wait for the task returned by `create_task` to finish. Python is evening warning you about that. Once `func_runner(not_a_coroutine)` completes, the event loop gives everything else one last chance to run, either until they complete or they yield back to the loop, whichever comes first. When you remove the sleep call, `hello_world` completes and you see both prints. When you leave it, control it returned to the loop and it never gets a chance to complete.

Answer (score 0):

This solution was made possible by [@dirn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978961/dirn) helpful diagnosis.

```
"""so_hello_world.py"""
import asyncio
from typing import Callable

background_tasks: set[asyncio.Task] = set()
end_program: asyncio.Event = asyncio.Event()


async def hello_world():
    global end_program
    print('Hello', end=' ')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('world.')
    end_program.set()

    
def not_a_coroutine():
    task = asyncio.create_task(hello_world())
    background_tasks.add(task)
    task.add_done_callback(background_tasks.discard)


async def main(func: Callable):
    func()
    await end_program.wait()


asyncio.run(main(not_a_coroutine))
```